# powerline font/symbol glitches

Tags: font, plugin-powerline

I'm new to vim and recently installed [powerline plugin](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html). I absolutely love using powerline with vim, but the symbols are not properly rendered. And I suspect I missed something here, can anyone help ???

Here is how it looks

[image: Here is how it looks]

Comment: Are you using a font modified for Powerline or using Unicode characters that you just pasted into vimrc or other config file? If the latter get patched fonts from here: https://github.com/powerline/fonts

Comment: Yeah thank you for your reply. Somehow I myself found fonts that are patched are work fine. Anyhow I'll up vote your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to install the elements such as the solid right arrows in your screenshot. Two are described here: [Powerline fonts installation](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#fonts-installation). One approach involves installing symbol fonts but these tend to have alignment problems such as you've seen. Similarly, pasting in Unicode characters into your configuration doesn't always work well.

The preferred way is to install "patched" fonts, regular fonts that have had the elements added. The elements in these are carefully sized proportional to the rest of the font set. You can find many of these fonts on Github at [powerline/fonts](http://github.com/powerline/fonts).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you'll need a patched font with power line symbols. I recommend installing a [Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts), as they'll cover just about any plug in for vim or your terminal.

Comment: Cheers friend :)